# How to convert strings to ASCII in QueryDSL?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I Have an Oracle DB that uses UTF-8. I am issuing some search queries, with `like`predicates to filter by some name column.

Since the data in the table are French and German names, they might contain accentuated characters, such as `àäèüéö`etc...

A `like` predicate that is written in JPQL looks like this (I simplified to keep just the relevant part):

```
...where lower(convert(item.value, 'US7ASCII')) like lower(convert(CONCAT('%',:query,'%'), 'US7ASCII'))
```

That yields the following SQL once converted to the Oracle dialect :

```
lower(convert(items4_.SSI_ITEM, 'US7ASCII')) like lower(convert('%'||?||'%', 'US7ASCII'))
```

Both sides of the `like`operator are converted to lower case and to the ?US7ASCII` character set, which removes accents. Note that both sides are converted by the database itself, using the same function. It makes the search "accent-insensitive", so to say.

Now, this works fine and is used for a relatively simple query, that returns names for the autocomplete of the field.

However, the main search query is way more complex and dynamic (lots of joins, dynamic criteria), and I am using QueryDSL to build it.

Is it possible to reproduce the above character conversion **using QueryDSL over JPA** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say that, but convert function is not JPA-compatible. It works for you just because hibernate interprets your JPQL as HQL. But QueryDSL supports only JPA standard (or you should use querydsl over hibernate).
You have several options, as I see:

1. Use hibernate instead of JPA
2. Create additional column, where you will store diacritics-free data (btw, your indexes will work better there too as I understand)
3. Do not use querydsl for this query but generate it by hand…

Looks like 2nd option is most easy to implement - just one pretty simple SQL migration, where you create additional column, insert normalized data there and create trigger for newly-added data to be automatically converted.

Comment: We ended up with the solution you describe (number 2). I was hoping to avoid it but it seems impossible with QueryDSL over JPA, and this query is way to complex to cleanly generate by hand.